# How can I tell when rendering has completed on ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working on a large scale Angular app that is tested using selenium webdriver. My concern is that the transcluding takes time, and I need feedback to let me know when transcluding finishes. This would allow me to wait until that trigger has fired to grab additional information. Is there a way to do this? Would something like `ng-repeat-end` always get processed after everything has been loaded?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to tell that the DOM has been completely rendered, but you can get an event triggered when the last element was $compiled and added to the DOM with a simple directive:

```
.directive('last', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope) {
            if(scope.$last) {
                $scope.emit('ngRepeat.finished');
                //or really anything you want to do
            }
        }
     }
});
```

Usage:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" last>
```

The thing to be aware of is that if "items" is changed, the ng-repeat is rebuilt, so you'll get another event.

Comment: surprised this isn't part of the ng-repeat directive already. Maybe a push request is in order. I would use a class instead of an emit though. Something like element.addClass('last') or mabe even ng-class="$last?'last':''"

Answer (score 1):

I'm unclear on if you want to get an event after an ng-repeat, or if you just want to wait until you can be guaranteed it has finished.

This is a driver wait that waits for loading in jQuery and $http, combined with the digest/render cycle in angular (you can chop out the part that isn't about digest/render if you don't need it). It's wrapped in a commented example of how you'd plug it into a C# selenium driver call, which should translate to whichever language you are using.

```js
/*var pageLoadWait = new WebDriverWait(WebDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout));
            pageLoadWait.Until<bool>(
                (driver) =>
                {
                    return (bool)JS.ExecuteScript(
@"*/
try {
  if (document.readyState !== 'complete') {
    return false; // Page not loaded yet
  }
  if (window.jQuery) {
    if (window.jQuery.active) {
      return false;
    } else if (window.jQuery.ajax && window.jQuery.ajax.active) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  if (window.angular) {
    if (!window.qa) {
      // Used to track the render cycle finish after loading is complete
      window.qa = {
        doneRendering: false
      };
    }
    // Get the angular injector for this app (change element if necessary)
    var injector = window.angular.element('body').injector();
    // Store providers to use for these checks
    var $rootScope = injector.get('$rootScope');
    var $http = injector.get('$http');
    var $timeout = injector.get('$timeout');
    // Check if digest
    if ($rootScope.$$phase === '$apply' || $rootScope.$$phase === '$digest' || $http.pendingRequests.length !== 0 || $rootScope.$$applyAsyncQueue.length > 0) {
      window.qa.doneRendering = false;
      return false; // Angular digesting or loading data
    }
    if (!window.qa.doneRendering) {
      // Set timeout to mark angular rendering as finished
      $timeout(function() {
        window.qa.doneRendering = true;
      }, 0);
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
} catch (ex) {
  return false;
}
/*");
                });*/
```

EDIT: After comment from Jackie, I noticed some situations where the page didn't fully render, adding `|| $rootScope.$$applyAsyncQueue.length > 0` appears to have fixed this.

Comment: This looks pretty close to what I did only what is with the timeout set to 0. Does that really allow the rendering to run before being put on the queue? I also created a wait_for_Ajax type method in a ruby monkey patch for angular and threw all this in it so it would work for all angular related calls

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer above is great but I think the point here is that even though the ng-repeat directive isolates scope, it has a scope variable that will tell you if it is the last one. If you are firing an event or something on the angular side the previous answer is probably the best ides. However, if your motives are purely testing based (like mine) this was enough...

```
ng-class="{'last': $last}"
```